# Compare IP Address whether they are in same network/range in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How can we compare if two IP are in same network/range or not ?
Suppose i get one IP Address as 172.24.18.257 and other one as 192.25.14.85 , here how i can check whether they are in same range/network or not ?
How can we do this MFC (VC++ ) ?

Any idea is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you literally just have the address - you don't have the netmask too? Where did they come from?

Comment: All IP adresses belong to one global network, `*.*.*.*`, so without additional information there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: @Dialecticus : Is there a way to global network from the IP address ?

Comment: @Swapnil: I don't understand the question, but this may be the answer: **Every IP** is part of `*.*.*.*`, so by definition 172.24.18.257 and 192.25.14.85 belong to same network.

Comment: @Dialecticus : Every IP is part of *.*.*.* (what does it mean) and how we can get this detail from IP ?

Comment: @Swapnil: IP addresses normally include an associated netmask. This allows networks to be logically subdivided (subnet) or aggregated (supernet). You can make assumptions about network ranges based on the IP address class but without the netmask you are just guessing. Do you have netmasks for the IP addresses you're comparing?

Comment: @Blastfurnace : how do we get netmasks from IP ?

Comment: @Swapnil: You can't determine the netmask given only the IP. Your DHCP server, network admin, or ISP will provide both numbers. The netmask will be a quad-dotted decimal (something like 255.255.255.0) or possibly CIDR notation (something like /24 suffix).

Comment: @Swapnil: You can read about IP addressing and netmasks in these articles. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to retreive network information from IP adress, but only if IP adress is on Internet. Consider this [link](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=network&host=64.34.119.12). On that page you will find out that IP adress of www.stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12) is in network range 64.34.0.0 - 64.34.255.255, or shall we say `64.34.*.*`. Now it's easy to compare network ranges of two IP adresses. This service is provided with [WHOIS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois).